# SWRevealController Programmatically

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to use the SWRevealController programmatically by calling `SWRevealController Delegate` in my ViewController but when I add the following to `viewDidLoad()` the barButtonItem does not work and the app crashes when it hits `addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())`. Below is the code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu2-black-32").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target:   self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

I am not sure what's causing this issue as this code works for one of my viewcontrollers and none of the others.

Looks like my self.revealViewController() is nil when I've edited the code to look like this:

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
      navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: 
      #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu2-black-
      32").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: 
      self.revealViewController(), action: 
      #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)))  self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
```

But I am not sure why it's nil.

Comment: what is `revealViewController()` ? might you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create bar button

```
 @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

In viewDidLoad you can add this one

```
 if self.revealViewController() != nil
        {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
         }
```

This works fine you can also customise menuButton(UIBarButtonItem)

Comment: but the issue is that my `self.revealController` is nil, so that code will never be executed

Comment: Did u add revealcontroller class .h & .m classes